# React make two async requests and passing the state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that needs to get a parameter (a unique provider number) from an ajax call. After the response I am using setState to set the new provider number and make another ajax call with the parameter from the first call and some more data. When I'm sending the second ajax the provider parameter from the first call is not included in the state. This parameter have to be set in the state in order to register the data and in case the second request fail, I don't want to make the first call again because the second request failed and did not use the provider parameter.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  type: 2,
  email: "",
  name: "",
  password: "",
  company: "",
  role: "",
  phone: "",
  provider: "",
});
const registerUser = useCallback(async () => {
  if (data.provider === "") {
    const provider = await getProvider();
    if (!provider) {
      console.log("Get Provider Error");
      return;
    }
  }
  try {
    const res = await api.registerUser(data);
    if (res.data.success) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
const getProvider = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await api.createUser({ TYPE: "S", TEXT1: data.name });
    if (res.data.TEXT3) {
      setData({ ...data, provider: res.data.TEXT3 });
      return res.data.TEXT3;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that, even when you updated the `data` inside the `registerUser`, you cannot get the updated `data` inside your `registerUser` until the next time you run it. This is due to the fact that most hooks will create a *slice* of the app state in one of its cycle and will not get the latest updated of the *slice* until it finish its cycle.
You can read more about it [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) (it wrote about `useEffect` but same apply to `useCallback` ).

This is a nice example of what happen in your code, simplified version [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-aryabhata-2mttp?file=/src/App.js)

If you want to mitigate this issue, I suggest using `useRef`. This will ensure the data in your hooks always up-to-date

```js
const dataRef = useRef({
  type: 2,
  email: "",
  name: "",
  password: "",
  company: "",
  role: "",
  phone: "",
  provider: "",
});
const registerUser = useCallback(async () => {
  if (data.provider === "") {
    const provider = await getProvider();
    if (!provider) {
      console.log("Get Provider Error");
      return;
    }
  }
  try {
    const res = await api.registerUser(dataRef.current);
    if (res.data.success) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
const getProvider = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await api.createUser({ TYPE: "S", TEXT1: data.name });
    if (res.data.TEXT3) {
      dataRef.current = { ...data, provider: res.data.TEXT3 };
      return res.data.TEXT3;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
});
```

One note is that `useRef` won't cause your component to re-render, so if you want your component your component to re-render when, let say your `data` get update then you should create a ref and a normal state and update both at the same time

Comment: Thank you, can you give me an example of how to use useRef in this case